Getting metadata into TIFF into programmatic way so that it's visible in QGIS
I am trying to get some copyright-specific metadata into a bunch of geotiffs. I've managed to get the necessary string to be visible in ArcGIS pro using arcpy, but I need to be able to do the same in QGIS.
This is where things get a bit difficult, I need to do the same thing so that it also appears in QGIS. I've tried gdal and rasterio but they seem to depend on editing/updating tags. I don't want the copyright string to show up in QGIS as TIFFTAG_COPYRIGHT=Data provided by blahBlah. (To be clear, "blahBlah" is just a placeholder) I want "Data provided by blahBlah". I want the string to show up in the rights field in information and/or metadata tab without TIFFTAG_COPYRIGHT=
Now I am aware that I can just write that in from the metadata tab and even save a .qmd file and load it again for other layers, but I am looking for a way to do it in a script-like manner so the relevant metadata can be put into the GeoTiff before they are loaded into QGIS and without opening a QGIS project. I am just looking for a library or function that would let me do that.

The copyright tifftag is the standard way for storing copyrigth information into TIFF https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/copyright.html. For me it feels a better option than application specific methods. If you do not like TIFFTAG_COPYRIGHT= then maybe some simple QGIS plugin could show metadata without the name of the tag. I do not know if such plugin exists already.
